# why is my cube not going forward and is just staying at it's position in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

using UnityEngine;

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour

{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void fixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 2000 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I am trying to make my cube go forward but it isn't moving forward. I am using the community version of visual studio 2019.

Comment: any errors in the console? did you attach the player's `rb` in the editor?

Comment: there were noo errors in the console and i have attached player the rigid body component

Comment: It is `FixedUpdate` not `fixedUpdate` .. is this a typo here or in your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that yo attach the `rb` in the editor or with code as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). Check code snippet below. Also you may want to try a bigger forca than `2000 * Time.deltaTime`. `Time.deltaTime` is a small value. Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). Try a bigger value, and check that the mass of the rigidbody is not very big so that the force is big enough to move the body.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float thrust = 1.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
    }
}
```

Comment: The truth is `Time.deltaTime` in this case makes no sense since `FixedUpdate` already runs frame-rate independent since it is already based on fixed time intervals ;)